# JSoup. I am trying to get text from a span that has multiple classes with strange names the compiler is not liking

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is what I have for the code:

```
enter code here text = text.toUpperCase();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + text + "?p=" + text).userAgent("Safari").get();

        Element temp = doc.selectFirst("span.Trsdu(0.3s).Fw(b).Fz(36px).Mb(-4px).D(ib)");

        System.out.println(temp);
```

Here is the span I am trying to get:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="35">1,119.50</span>
```

I am trying to get 1119.50 but have been unable to. Please help! I am using netbeans as my java IDE. I am new to JSoup so please help me if I am doing something ignorant.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't select it with the `data-reactid` attribute?

Comment: can you explain? I am new to JSoup and don't know exactly what you mean. sorry lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should get you the value you are looking for by selecting the first span the `data-reactid` you are looking for:

```
Element test = doc.select("span[data-reactid='35']").first();
System.out.println(test.text());
```

Comment: It's weird cause I use that and it gives me the data-reactid=43 instead of 35 and its really strange

Comment: Are you sure? It grabs the 35 value even when I add an element with data-reactid=43 into my sample html.

Comment: Ahhh yes it is working now. I think it had something to do with me using the userAgent method. Thank you

Comment: When i took out the userAgent("Safari") it gave me the correct output